# Python - Extract important string information

Tags: python, string

I have the following string

http://example.com/variable/controller/id32434242423423234?param1=321&param2=4324342

How in best way to extract id value, in this case - 32434242423423234

Regardz,
Mladjo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html), e.g.:

```
import re

s = "http://example.com/variable/controller/id32434242423423234?param1=321&param2=4324342"

m = re.search(r'controller/id(\d+)\?',s)
if m:    
    print "Found the id:", m.group(1)
```

If you need the value as an number rather than a string, you can use `int(m.group(1))`.  There are plenty of other ways of doing this that might be more appropriate, depending on the larger goal of your code, but without more context it's hard to say.

Comment: Though it is not strictly necessary in this case, please, add `r` before a string with a regex to avoid gotchas such as `'[\f]'` (note the difference between `list('\f')` and `list(r'\f')`).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: thanks for the suggestion - I've made that change.  (Excellent username, BTW :))

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> res=urlparse.urlparse("http://example.com/variable/controller/id32434242423423234?param1=321&param2=4324342")
>>> res.path
'/variable/controller/id32434242423423234'
>>> import posixpath
>>> posixpath.split(res.path)
('/variable/controller', 'id32434242423423234')
>>> directory,filename=posixpath.split(res.path)
>>> filename[2:]
'32434242423423234'
```

Using `urlparse` and `posixpath` might be too much for this case, but I think it is the clean way to do it.

Comment: On Windows `os.path.split()` doesn't work as you expect. Use `posixpath.split()` instead.

Comment: That is interesting; I am using Python 2.6.5 on Windows XP. What version of Windows does that not work with?

Comment: `os.path.split()` on Windows uses both separators r'\/' and calls `splitdrive()` on the argument - you don't want that, just use `posixpath.split()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s
'http://example.com/variable/controller/id32434242423423234?param1=321&param2=4324342'
>>> s.split("id")
['http://example.com/variable/controller/', '32434242423423234?param1=321&param2=4324342']
>>> s.split("id")[-1].split("?")[0]
'32434242423423234'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

While Regex is THE way to go, for simple things I have written a [string parser](https://github.com/hgrecco/stringparser). In a way, is the (uncomplete) reverse operation of a string formatting operation with [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/). This is very convenient because it means that you do not have to learn another way of specifying the strings.

For example:

```
>>> 'The answer is {:d}'.format(42)
The answer is 42
```

The parser does the opposite:

```
>>> Parser('The answer is {:d}')('The answer is 42') 
42
```

For your case, if you want an int as output

```
>>> url = 'http://example.com/variable/controller/id32434242423423234?param1=321&param2=4324342'
>>> fmt = 'http://example.com/variable/controller/id{:d}?param1=321&param2=4324342'
>>> Parser(fmt)(url)
32434242423423234
```

If you want a string:

```
>>> fmt = 'http://example.com/variable/controller/id{:s}?param1=321&param2=4324342'
>>> Parser(fmt)(url)
32434242423423234
```

If you want to capture more things in a dict:

```
>>> fmt = 'http://example.com/variable/controller/id{id:s}?param1={param1:s}&param2={param2:s}'
>>> Parser(fmt)(url)
{'id': '32434242423423234', 'param1': '321', 'param2': '4324342'}
```

or in a tuple:

If you want to capture more things in a dict:

```
>>> fmt = 'http://example.com/variable/controller/id{:s}?param1={:s}&param2={:s}'
>>> Parser(fmt)(url)
('32434242423423234', '321', '4324342')
```

Give it a try, it is hosted [here](https://github.com/hgrecco/stringparser)